# How to work with timezonecode in FakeXrm?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a problem here I have wrote a UnitTest that looks like this

```
        Entity userSettings = new Entity("usersettings");
        userSettings.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        userSettings["timezonecode"] = 71;
        userSettings["systemuserid"] = systemUser.ToEntityReference();

        fakedContext.CallerId = systemUser.ToEntityReference();
        fakedContext.Initialize(new List<Entity>()
        {
            workOrder, owner, invoiceNote, systemUser, userSettings
        });
```

I Have specified a timezonecode in my unitTest, and I have a plugin that returns me an error in this lines `TimeZoneCode = timeZoneCode.Value,` 
The whole method looks like this

```
   private DateTime RetrieveLocalTimeFromUtcTime(DateTime UtcTime, int? timeZoneCode, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var request = new LocalTimeFromUtcTimeRequest
        {
            TimeZoneCode = timeZoneCode.Value,
            UtcTime = UtcTime
        };

        var response = (LocalTimeFromUtcTimeResponse)service.Execute(request);

        return response.LocalTime;
    }
```

Please, any suggestions what's I am doing wrong.

Comment: "Please, any suggestions what's I am doing wrong." A description what is happening or not happening would be nice. But generally your problem is that you are dealing wtih timezones in your code. That is one of the things you should never do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Can you include the code where you take the `timezonecode` value from `userSettings` and pass it to your `RetrieveLocalTimeFromUtcTime` method? Also, what is the error message you get?

Comment: I just figured this out, and what was the problem LocalTimeFromUtcTimeRequest is not supported yet in FakeXrm, look here  https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/issues/340